# Selecting different graphics for the view depending on model type

Tags: c#, oop, model-view-controller, mvvm, separation-of-concerns

### Introduction

I'm building a relatively simple program to design layouts on a perfboard (simple diy-friendly circuit board). I'm using WinForms's `System.Drawing` to draw the circuit board. I need to be able to serialize relevant parts of the model representing the perfboard and it's components.

### TL;DR

- I have models of different types (not necessarily types as in *classes*)
- My views need some way of deciding what graphic (image/drawing routine) to use depending on that type.
- How is this normally done in MVC/MVVM/whatever?
- I would like to avoid type-checking or storing a `ComponentType` property as a string/enum.
- Model needs to be serializable (probably binary and not XML/JSON).

### Goals

- Follow some kind of model-view separation (just mushing it all together would solve this specific problem, but likely introduce new problems in the future).
- An actually object-oriented approach, i.e. avoid type-checking, storing a `ComponentType` property as a string/enum, and so on.

### Ideas

Let's say I have a `Component` class, this could either be a class using composition-over-inheritance or an interface which is in turn implemented by discrete classes such as `Wire` and `Transistor`. I then need to draw these `Component` objects somehow to the window. A simple approach would be to have a `Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics)` method on the class, but then that would totally break the model-view separation.

If I somewhat follow MVC or MVVM (or whatever separation pattern really) I would have a `ComponentView` of some sort (same as with the model: either one composed class or subclasses). Somehow this view needs to decide what type of component it's representing and based on that choose a graphic to display (maybe a simple interface with a Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics) method or whatever).

### Basic model

```
    public class Perfboard
    {
        List<Component> components;

        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable Components => components;

        public Perfboard()
        {
        }

        public Perfboard(int width, int height)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
        }

        // ...
    }

    public class Component
    {
        // This will have a position used for the graphic maybe?

        // The component's legs needs to be represented either in here, or maybe I build the perfboard
        // as a Cell[w,h] array and have the cells refer to the Component...
    }
```

### Possible views

```
    public class PerfboardView
    {
        public Perfboard Board { get; private set; }

        // Either I have a list of ComponentView objects here, or they're just generated on the fly when drawing.

        // Basically just X and Y for the cursor and a Draw method
        public BoardCursor Cursor { get; private set; }

        public PerfboardView(Perfboard board)
        {
            Board = board;
        }

        public void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
            g.TranslateTransform(Cursor.X * -25.4f, Cursor.Y * -25.4f);
            DrawHoles(g);

            // Somehow draw the components...

            Cursor.Draw(g);
        }

        // ...
    }
```

### Disclaimer

The structure of the model is definitely not set in stone in any way. I feel that I'm missing something obvious so a completely different approach is welcomed!